# Group by TIMESTAMP`S Date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to group by Timestamp`s Date in oracle so far I used `to_char`. But I need another way. I tried like below:

```
    SELECT d.summa,
           d.FILIAL_CODE,
           to_char(d.DATE_ACTION, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    FROM table1 d
    WHERE d.action_id = 2
      AND d.date_action Between to_date('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') AND to_date('01.03.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
    GROUP BY to_char(d.DATE_ACTION, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

**table1**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
summa      |  filial_code    | date_action
--------------------------------------------------
100000.00  |  2100           | 2016-09-13 11:04:32
320000.12  |  3200           | 2016-09-12 21:04:58
400000.00  |  2100           | 2016-09-13 15:12:45
510000.12  |  3200           | 2016-09-15 09:30:58
------------------------------------------------------
```

I need like below

```
-------------------------------------------
summa      |  filial_code    | date_action
------------------------------------------
500000.00  |  2100           | 2016-09-13 
320000.12  |  3200           | 2016-09-12 
510000.12  |  3200           | 2016-09-15 
------------------------------------------
```

But I need **except** `to_char` function. I tried `trunc` but i could not do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `TRUNC` should actually convert it to a date and remove the time part, but you also need to handle your other columns. Either group by them or use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT SUM( d.summa ) AS summa,
       d.FILIAL_CODE,
       TRUNC(d.DATE_ACTION) AS date_action
FROM table1 d
WHERE d.action_id = 2
  AND d.date_action Between to_date('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
                        AND to_date('01.03.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
GROUP BY TRUNC(d.DATE_ACTION), d.FILIAL_CODE
```

Comment: A minor clarification, `TRUNC` does not "remove" the time-part but will (with the default second argument) truncate the time part back to midnight of the same day; so it will still have a time-part but it would be `00:00:00` allowing all rows on the same day to be grouped together as they would have the same year-to-second values.